# Back button is not showing in navigation bar?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, uinavigationitem

I,m building an article read app for iPad and using split view controller.
Master view contains menu list and detail view controller contains list of article.
Clicking on list of articles it opens in a new view and i’m using a segue and navigation controller to connect detail view controller and Next view in which article opens.
Segue with Modal style.I’m facing a problem there is no back button when article opens in a next view.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article view is being presented modally, so there is no back button. If you change your storyboard so that you're presenting the article view with a push segue, you'll get a back button. If you want to maintain the modal presentation, you can add a UIBarButton item to the article view (ie, add a UIToolbar or embed the article view controller in a UINavigationController so that you can update the UIBarButtonItems of the navigation toolbar).

Comment: @ azsromej thanksWhen i Applied push segue my article is not open in a full screen.

Comment: Try one of the following in your storyboard. In the second, the Article view controller is embedded in its own navigation controller.
(1): [Detail]-(modal segue)-[Article]
(2): [Detail]-(modal segue)-[Nav Controller]-[Article]
In both situations you're presenting a modal view controller, so there won't be a back button that dismisses the view controller. You can add a Done button and call dismissViewControllerAnimated: yourself to return to the Detail view controller.

Comment: @ azsromej,i'm not getting your point could you please explain it more cleary

Comment: @ azsromej,I have applied method You have mention but my app is crashing on clicking bar button, here is my code: UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(buttonAction:)]; self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=backButton; –

Comment: and i have used this method - (void) buttonAction: (UIButton*) sender { hsIpadViewController* modalView2 = [[hsIpadViewController alloc] init]; [self presentViewController:modalView2 animated:YES completion:^{ [modalView2 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }]; } –

Comment: In your buttonAction, you're creating a new instance of the hsIpadViewController, then presenting it and immediately dismissing it. Try calling [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES] within buttonAction instead (ie, you want to dismiss the currently-presented instance of that view controller).

Comment: @ azsromej i have applied this its working,it takes the view to previous view on clicking bar button but after a second app crash.    - (void) buttonAction: (UIButton*) sender {
    hsIpadViewController* modalView2 = [[hsIpadViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController* presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [presentingViewController presentViewController:modalView2 animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}

Comment: I'm confused about the reason you're trying to present modalView2 when you tap the Done button. You likely only need the call to dismissViewControllerAnimated in the buttonAction method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57940/discussion-between-daljeet-and-azsromej).